# Showing that $u(x,y)=xy\ln|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|$ belongs to $ H^2$, but not to $C^2$.

Tags: limits, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I want to show that that $u(x,y)=xy\ln|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|$ is $C^1(\Omega)$ and $H^2(\Omega)$, but not $C^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega=B_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)$ is the ball centered at $0$ and with radius $1/2$.

To prove that $u$ is $C^1$ I computed explicitly and used polar coordinates for $r\rightarrow 0,$ no problems.

The second derivatives exists, and are given by
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{3xy}{(x^2+y^2)\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2\ln^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
$$
How can I prove that this function is not continuous at $0$? And how can I prove that this is a weak derivative of for $u$ and belongs to $L^2$? Is there a way that does not envolves using directly the definition?

Comment: To check discontinuity, it's enough to do it on a line, e.g. $x=y$. To check $L^2$-integrability, I'd simply look at the integral and bound it. The weak derivative part is more subtle, have you thought about it? (or had experience with similar problems?)

Comment: I managed to prove that the second weak derivatives exists (the first weaks derivatives exists trivially for $u$ is $C^1$). Now the only problem is to prove that the second derivatives are $L^2$. I couldn't find a bound for it.

Comment: Each of the terms above is bounded by $\frac{1}{\ln r}$ times a constant (where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$), and you can check in polar coordinates that this is in $L^2$. I'm quite curious how you showed existence of second weak derivatives without first checking $L^2$-integrability - if you write it down, I could check.